# Placement of Html.BeginForm() in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While in asp.net master page use to contain `form control`. I am not able to figure out, where is the correct location to place `Html.BeginForm()`. Is it `Layout Page` or the `View`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place one in any one location that you need a form. This normally means inside a view, as you would want a different action on each page/form rather than the same one across the site.

The limitation of one form per page that webforms has does not exist in MVC - you can have more than one form per page.

Comment: Hi Oded, Using MVC 3, I have generated a strongly typed View. This contains 5-6 input fields (WCF Reqeust) and some output fields(WCF Response). Should I include response section also in `Html.BeginForm()`

Comment: @autrevo - I don't know. I have no idea what you are trying to do with your form and why you are exposing WCF data on your UI.

Comment: Hi Oded, I have a set of WCF services, For testing purposes, I am trying to create a simple MVC app, to invoke these serivces and display the result.

Comment: @autrevo - So, for input use a form. You don't have to have a form to display the output (and that should be a separate view anyways).

Comment: I have to display request and response, simultaneously. Partial view is the way to go, it seems in this case. Because I shall not be able to make a single strongly typed view with Request & Response togther.

Answer (score 1):

Form element should wrap up your input elements and textarea's.
Thus if your inputs are  in your layout or master page - you can have a form there.
But most of the time your forms are in your views, where you create or edit data.